# How to get the client's ip from the request?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to get the ip addresses of clients when request are being made

But I always get the same result:

```
::1
```

How to get exactly the client's ip address, I made requests from different devices, but the result is the same

```
  @Get(':id')
  async get(@Req() request: Request, @Param('id') id: string) {
    console.log(request.ip);
    return this.adService.findOne({ id });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request object contains a property called `socket`, which is actually a `net.Socket` object. This object has a `remoteAddress` property which holds the IP address of the call.

`request.socket.remoteAddress`

Please also note, that if the server is behind a proxy, you should be using the request headers  `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']`